# Join on a lookup table, to display the whole of one table where id's match?

Tags: database, sqlite, database-design, inner-join

I have three tables:

planner:

[image]

lookup:

[image]

ingredients:

[image]

Can anyone help me return all of the ingredients from the ingredients table which are in the recipes that are in the planner table. I'm using sqlite. I've setup the objective-c to step through each row returned and add it to an object, I just cant get the correct rows returning.

```
ingredients.serial = lookup.ingredient_serial
planner.recipe_id = lookup.recipe_serial
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What have you tried?  This should work:

```
select
  planner.cell_id
, planner.recipe_name
, planner.day
, ingredients.quantity
, ingredients.measurement
, ingredients.description
from 
  planner inner join lookup
    on planner.recipe_id = lookup.recipe_serial
  inner join ingredients 
    on lookup.ingredient_serial = ingredients.serial
where planner.is_populated = 1
order by
  planner.cell_id
, ingredients.serial
```

Comment: This will return an ingredient multiple times if it is used by multiple recipes. The question did not ask for values from the `planner` table.

Comment: @CL - The question is non-specific about what is required. I don't think it is unreasonable to assume that the point in looking up ingredients is to find them in context of their recipe, so showing the ingredient in each recipe in which it is used makes sense. If OP doesn't care about the planner, they can omit those columns.

Answer (score 1):

Translating your description into SQL gives this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ingredients
WHERE serial IN (SELECT ingredient_serial
                 FROM lookup
                 WHERE recipe_serial IN (SELECT recipe_id
                                         FROM planner
                                         WHERE is_populated))
```

Comment: Subselecting when you can just inner join is obtuse and very probably inefficient, unless the query engine is smart enough to convert your subqueries into joins.

Comment: SQLite implements joins as nested loops, which end up being implemented just the same way as these subselects.